# Bad Request Error encountered with GraphQL DotNet

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I'm using [GraphQL.Net](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) and getting the following when trying to use the API.

```
{
  "version": {
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": -1,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "application\/json; charset=utf-8"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 400,
  "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
  "headers": [

  ],
  "requestMessage": {
    "version": {
      "major": 2,
      "minor": 0,
      "build": -1,
      "revision": -1,
      "majorRevision": -1,
      "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": null,
    "method": {
      "method": "GET"
    },
    "requestUri": null,
    "headers": [

    ],
    "properties": {

    }
  },
  "isSuccessStatusCode": false
}
```

It is quite vague as to what the cause of the error is. Is there something wrong with the setup of my queries / types? Or is it in my request? Is it about authentication?

I'm not sure which code to share, so I uploaded my API library at: https://github.com/jonasarcangel/GraphQLIssue

Request payload is as follows (using Apollo Angular):

```
{
  "operationName": "configsQuery",
  "variables": {
    "id": "",
    "module": "admin\/configs",
    "name": "canActivate"
  },
  "query": "query configsQuery($id: String, $module: String, $name: String) {\n  configs(id: $id, module: $module, name: $name) {\n    id\n    createdBy\n    createdDate\n    updatedBy\n    updatedDate\n    name\n    module\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
}
```

Comment: Well what is your GraphQL controller outputting? Have you tried debugging that?

Comment: This is what I have logged. https://github.com/jonasarcangel/GraphQLIssue/blob/master/output.txt

Comment: I'm not really interested in what you have logged, have you debugged the controller?

Comment: I get prerendering timeout with VS Code, as it takes longer than 50 seconds. I'll install and try it with VS for Mac to do that.

Comment: So does it enter the controller at all? I have no idea what a "prerendering timeout" is.

Comment: Does this issue exist when requesting from `/ui/playground`? Share us the complete sample to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "A query is required." Something is wrong with my request.

Comment: The issue is with my request. I'm sending the query in the body of the POST request. I modified my method to get the query [FromBody] and it worked.